# JQuery Ajax Form appending query string

Tags: forms, jquery

I am having an issue with using ajaxSubmit with [jQuery Form](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) - even when POSTing a form it will occasionally have all parameters serialized into a querystring. They are included as form data too but the querystring will occasionally esceed the server's maximum url length.

Does anyone know why this is happening slash if there is some way to prevent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you used the `type` of ajaxform?This will help you to send it as `POST`.Just set the `type` to post.Its `GET` by default
Like

```
$('#yourFrmId').ajaxForm({
  type : 'Post',
  ...... so on
});
```